# Adding items to the ScrollView dynamically make it doesn't scroll

Tags: android, dynamic, scrollview

I have a simple layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:padding="15dp">


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/scrollLayout">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I inflate the outer `RelativeLayout` to retrieve the inner `LinearLayout` to put items in it.

```
RelativeLayout relative =  (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.gradient_pick_view, null);
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) relative.findViewById(R.id.scrollLayout);
```

After that I created a method to add some buttons to it:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     LinearLayout wrapper = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.button_wrapper, null);
     Button button = (Button)wrapper .findViewById(R.id.button);
     view.addView(layout);
}
```

Everything works fine, but it doesn't scroll.
What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the screenshot (displaying 7 of 10 buttons):
[image]

I forgot to mention - I'm using a `MaterialDialog` library and add this RelativeLayout as a custom view to a dialog.

Comment: Are the buttons being added ?

Comment: yep! I add 10 of them, 7 are displayed

Comment: remove the linear Layout.. add the button in Scroll View.Let me know if it works or  not

Comment: @Spectre, what's the purpose of parent `RelativeLayout`? You mat remove it and `ScrollView` would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the following attribute to your scrollview,

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

above attribute is used to make your scrollview to use entire screen of your application.

Comment: and If I don't want to fill the entire screen?

Comment: what entire screen here means is the height and width that you have provided it will fill that area fully.

Answer (score 0):

I had a false parameter passed to a `customView` in a `MaterialDialog`.

```
dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(activity)
                    .title(R.string.about)
                    .customView(view, true)
                    .positiveText(R.string.changing_fragments)
                    .show();
```

As doc says:

> If wrapInScrollView is true, then the library will place your custom view inside of a ScrollView for you. This allows users to scroll your custom view if necessary (small screens, long content, etc.). However, there are cases when you don't want that behavior. This mostly consists of cases when you'd have a ScrollView in your custom layout, including ListViews, RecyclerViews, WebViews, GridViews, etc. The sample project contains examples of using both true and false for this parameter.

Now it's working.